# How to check for Session state in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a web application which communicates with a database using SQLAlchemy. The connection is done using certificates and keys. The problem is that the certificates are changing every now and then while the application is still online (which means that the sqlalchemy session is already initiated with the old certificates). Hence, when the certificates have changed, I get an psycopg2.OperationalError saying that the connection was closed unexpectedly.
I must restart the app for the session to load the new certificates when initiating to fix the problem.

My session is created once when the app is starting and then I use the same session for all database actions.

My question is how can I check if the session is still valid before using it?

Many thanks

Comment: Consider not using the same session all the time, if the app is even slightly longer running.

Comment: I don't want to open multiple connections to the database